# I want to reverse this code using removeClass

Tags: jquery

Basically i am created one message box when we click on Open Button message is pull on display, now i want when click on close button the message is return to the message box.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.frame').click(function() { 
        $('.top').addClass('open'); 
        $('.message').addClass('pull');
```

Comment: First you can removeClass like open and pull then you can use focus event to go to return to message box

Comment: I think you are looking for `removeClass()`. But due to very less code provided, i can't say that where/how it will be fit. You have to do it yourself. Otherwise try to provide a working example of your problem and then we can help you to solve it.

Comment: Click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58315749/edit) then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve]

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie More likely toggleClass

Answer (score 1):

Since you give us very poor information about the code you can try some of this tips

```
// .frame class should toggle the windows ? 

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.frame').click(function(){
if($('.top').hasClass('open')){
  $('.top').removeClass('open');
  $('.message').removeClass('pull');
}else{
  $('.top').addClass('open');
  $('.message').addClass('pull');
}
 });
});
```

Comment: @AnkitaNangare post your html than so we can see your structure

Comment: https://codepen.io/Voica/pen/XamEaN .. can you check this link this is similar to my question

Comment: @AnkitaNangare i change the code and will work you, need to play with css animation timing to match the close animation only